# Dell 412 motherboard support Intel Core 2 Quad Q9550 processor?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, quad-core

Does anyone knows if  a Dell 412 motherboard support Intel Core 2 Quad Q9550 processor? I have  now a Intel core 2 Duo E6850 and 12GB internal memory and it works great.

Comment: Have you checked their website?

Comment: Yes just "old" info there as i use to bee...

Comment: You have 12 gb of memory yet you have a dual core...

Comment: Bad news that's not possible on the motherboard. Liessss

Comment: And not it doesn't support quad core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is no. As you can see here: http://www.findlaptopdriver.com/dell-0tp412-specs/

Not only does it not support a quad core. But on top of that it doesn't support your aclaimed 12gb of RAM.

Comment: I have Bios 15 from 04/30/12 and use 12GB ram an it works great!